# Unstack/split dataframe and write parts/chunks of dataframe to multiple csv's assigned to keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

**Problem**

I'm reading in multiple csv which match a certain pattern, concatenating them into a dataframe and doing some processing within the frame (e.g. fill datetime gaps, build averages etc.). In the next step I try to unstack the dataframe,  and write them into seperate csv files(name them as the imported files + extension) to same directory where they were imported from.
The concatenated processed dataframe looks as follows:

```
                Datetime    Value
0    2017-03-03 12:15:00    2.3
1    2017-03-03 12:30:00    2.1
...
n    2017-12-19 12:15:00    5.3
0    2017-05-03 12:15:00    1.3
1    2017-05-03 12:30:00    3.1
...
m    2017-12-19 12:15:00    7.3
...
```

My code so far:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

    pattern = "*whatever*.csv" 
    directory_path = "mypath"
    files = glob.iglob(directory_path + '/**/' + pattern, recursive=True)

    def get_files():
        dfs = (pd.read_csv(filename)
                for filename in files)
        df = pd.concat(dfs)

    def process_df():
     .... # do some processing
        return processed_df

    '''this part of code does basically what i want'''
    def write_to_csv()
        dict_ = {}
        for filename in files:
            dict_[file] = pd.read_csv(file)
        for file in dict_:
            with open(os.path.splitext(file)[0] + "_gaps_filled.csv", 'w') as f:
            dict_[filename].to_csv(f, sep=',', index=False, header=False)
```

The `def write_to_csv()` does basically want I want for not concatenated / processed data.

**Question**

How can split/unstack the concatenated processed dataframe, assign the correct filename to the unstacked/splitted chunk and write it to a csv file in a loop?

***Desired Resulut**

Read in matched csv files into dataframe--->process dataframe--->write processed chunks to the corresponding csv filename and directory

```
a.csv                  a   some data                              a_pro.csv
b.csv    to df------->     some data   process--->[]   to_csv-->  b_pro.csv
c.csv                       ...                                   c_pro.csv
                       b   some data 
                           some data
                       ...
                       c   some data
                           some data
                       ...
```

**My Approach**

I tried to set keys (`pd.concat(dfs, keys=filenames`) so I can assign the filename to corresponding chunk in the concatenated dataframe. But in my `def process_df()` function im using the `groupby` method so the keys get "lost".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One transparent solution is to simply add a column with the filename during your processing.

Then, when you want to output to separate files, just filter by filename and output accordingly.

Your code may look something like this:

```
dfs = {i: pd.read_csv(i).assign(filename=i) for i in filenames}
df = pd.concat(dfs.values(), ignore_index=True)

# do your processing here

for k in filenames:
    df[df['filename'] == k].drop('filename', 1).to_csv(k+'pro', index=False)
```